# android listview item height

Tags: android, listview, row, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

Why when i use SimpleCursorAdapter for ListView i have items height in ListView like this - [image: listview image]

(My code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982948/sqlite-and-populating-list-view-android))

**But when using arrays Listview items have big height**

[image: listview big]

(I learn listview based on [this](http://androidpeople.com/android-listview-example/))

Row layout for item listview is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**So My question is why there is a difference in row heights when using ArrayAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter?**

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361423/android-get-listview-item-height/12513898#12513898

Answer (score 136):

```
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

seemed no effect.

```
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

changed the height for me

Comment: @Bamboo, how to set this in the program?

Comment: add android:minHeight as attribute to the textview element or set it programmaticly from java codes

Answer (score 37):

The trick for me was not setting the height -- but instead setting the minHeight. This must be applied to the root view of whatever layout your custom adapter is using to render each row.

Comment: Spent almost an hour trying to find a solution. This is exactly what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use padding on the list item layout so space is added on the edges of the item (just increasing the font size won't do that).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I did something like that :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setHeight(30);
    textView.setMinimumHeight(30);

    /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    return view;
}
```

You must put the both fields textView.setHeight(30);
                    textView.setMinimumHeight(30); or it won't change anything. For me it worked & i had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The height of list view items are adjusted based on its contents. In first image, no content. so height is very minimum. In second image, height is increased based on the size of the text. Because, you specified android:layout_height="wrap_content".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solutions;
It is my getView() in BaseAdapter subclass:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent,false);
        System.out.println("In");
    }
    convertView.setMinimumHeight(100);
    return convertView;
}
```

Here i have set ListItem's minimum height to 100;

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution(There is a nested LinearLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_arrow_top_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="全部收支"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unnecessary nesting is bad practice and bad for performance. The nested LinearLayout doesn't make a different here, either.